# How to update a polymorhic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorhpic model as follows:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :uploadable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :photo
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :upload, :as => :uploadable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The user uploads a photo in a fancy box iframe using the ajax hack with the jquery-file-upload plugin.

The uploaded photo is saved in the uploads table without  uploadable_id or uploadable_type as I don't have the parent  Message yet.

How can I update the Upload model with the Message id and type when I save the Message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.upload = @upload
@message.save